# Python formatted literal string and thousand separator

Tags: python, string, format

Is there a way to combine python3.6 formatted literal strings ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) with [format specifications](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

`print('Count: {:,}'.format(count)) # Count: 10,000`

`print(f'Count: {count}') # Count: 10000`

The closest thing I can think of is using  the `format` function like this:
`print(f'Count: {format(count, "6,d")}') # Count: 10,000 # can use "6,d" or any other format that puts thousands separators`

Is this the best way to do that?

Comment: `print(f'Count: {count:,}')`? There are examples in the PEP you've linked showing this: [*"optional format specifiers maybe be \[sic\] included inside the f-string, separated from the expression (or the type conversion, if specified) by a colon"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [link you gave](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification):

> F-strings use the same format specifier mini-language as str.format.
>   Similar to **str.format()**, optional format specifiers maybe be included
>   inside the f-string, separated from the expression (or the type
>   conversion, if specified) by a colon. If a format specifier is not
>   provided, an empty string is used.

as for your example:

```
>>> count = 10000
>>> print('Count: {:,}'.format(count))
Count: 10,000
>>> print(f'Count: {count:,}')
Count: 10,000
```

Comment: Totally missed that paragraph. Thanks!